# SugarCRM Web Services Rest API Ionic Framework AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, sugarcrm

I customize the application web sugarCRM to my need and I have to realize a hybrid mobile application using Ionic framework and AngularJS. 
I want to make a authentication from the mobile application.
In my folder js/factory/userProvider.js i have this code

```
app.factory('userProvider', function($rootScope, $http) { 
    function signIn(User) { 
       var url = 'The url of the api '; 
       $http.post(url,Userser).success(function (response) { 
          console.log(response); 
       }); 
       return{ signIn: signIn } 
    }
});
```

My big problem is that SugarCRM already has web services and I don't know the url to use for the authentication.

In my folder js/controllers/homepageController i have this code :

```
app
.controller('homepageIndex', function ($scope) { }) 
.controller('homepageLogin', function ($scope, userProvider) {    
    $scope.user = {}; 
    $scope.signIn = function (user) { userProvider.signIn(user); } 
});
```

So I want to know how to use the web services of sugarCRM to authenticate in my mobile application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SugarCRM's URL is specific for each company. To get started in your application, you are going to have to ask the user, the URL, Username and Password.

Once, you have this information you can use oauth to obtain the information needed to process requests. To use oauth you need to POST to SugarCRM URL/rest/v10/oauth2/token

Comment: i dont have accees to http://127.0.0.1:100/suitecrm/rest/v10/oauth2/token " Object not found " .in folder suitecrm i dont found rest but in suitecrm/service i find just v4_1 !!

Comment: You marked the answer as the solution but obviously it didn't work, what a joke